# Hide div when input has text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This ain't for use on a larger scale just a small personal site, but how would I go about hiding a div when input matches a query ? I've seen this fiddle, however it just hides div based on any input, whereas I'm looking for it to match an exact value.

http://jsfiddle.net/P78Wc/

I thought changing

```
if ($(this).val() != '') $('#yeah').show();
```

to

```
if ($(this).val() != 'word') $('#yeah').show();
```

It would have to match that word however that's not the case.

Any help would be great thanks.

Solution is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/96urc0aj/

Change the word test to the word you wish to use.

Comment: Let's read it out loud. "If value of this element does not match "word" show an element with the id of yeah." Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Its not exactly clear what your ultimate goal is here, one of your fiddles seems to work exactly how you were trying to describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above includes `!=` which means does not equal, but to check when the input MATCHES a query use `$(this).val()==="query"`. To clarify, you should use `===` not `!=`. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, I'll post a fiddle at the bottom in case anyone else wonders

Comment: @Pornsera, That's great! Mark my answer as the answer by clicking the check mark by my answer or upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (written from the perspective of always showing):

```
<label for="db">Type whatever</label>
<input type="text" name="amount" />
</select>
<div id="yeah">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === 'work' ) {
        $('#yeah').hide();
    } else if ($('#yeah').is(":hidden") && $(this).val() !== 'work'){
        $('#yeah').show(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide the value when you have input as "word"

```
<label for="db">Type whatever</label>
<input type="text" name="amount" />
<div id="yeah" style="display:block;">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'word') $('#yeah').hide();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone need this solution in pure JavaScript:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  const yeah = document.querySelector('#yeah');
  
    if (target.value === 'test') {
    yeah.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      yeah.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```html
<label for="db">Type whatever or "test" word to see button</label>
<input type="text" name="amount" />
</select>
<div id="yeah" style="display:none;">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```